# Should I focus on a Location Page or Landing Page for SEO efforts?

Tags: seo, local-seo, landing-page

I am a franchisee with a location page (`http://example.com/locations/florida/south-brandon`) but since it isn't mobile friendly and lacks a good CTA, I created a landing page for AdWords (`http://www.myexample.com`/).  I've also been using the later as the location page and directing my link building efforts there.

I want to start a blog and other SEO efforts, but I'm not sure which page I should be trying to rank.  Obviously I'll need to switch some links and I'll take a short-term hit if I switch; but is it better to just go ahead and do it?  I'm torn and I need some suggestions based on experience to point me in the right direction!

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking, but just in case, please forgive me. If you do web work, make it on your own site so that you can retain the effort for the future. Blogs are great especially if you can produce small amounts of strategic content designed to focus on narrow keywords and narrow sub-topics of the overall topic.

Comment: For a good answer, it's really important to know what's the difference between the two. Is it just for an address and location? Or are the users carrying out transactions that can be done only on the original site, to which they will be redirected eventually? Adding a link could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment based on experience, as I am relatively new to the field. However, I can give you an answer. Some answer is better than no answer, right?

There are advantages and disadvantages for both approaches. The disadvantages are that you might be getting some benefits on local search because of the page rank of example.com and adding your efforts to it to make it better will be easier. All your referral traffic will come to myexample.com, but sales will happen at example.com, right? It is possible that you miss some traffic in between. If what I understand is correct, it will take three clicks from adwords (to myexample.com to example.com to action button). That is a lot of chance for considerable traffic loss.

However, the advantage is that you already mentioned, you can customize the page to your needs. That means that you can create better search engine optimized pages, better content and optimize it for mobiles. It is all a matter of weighing the advantages and the disadvantages.

Hope this helped